# Page Reload after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a simple call ajax to pass a formdata to php

AJAX CODE

```
$('#upload').on('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#texto').val($(this).val());
    if ($('#lefectuado').css('display') === 'block') {

        var file_data = $('#upload').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);

        var session;
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "http://localhost/sitePAW/exam.php",
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (text) {
                session = JSON.parse(text);

                $("#Titulo").val(session.Title);
                $("#Autor").val(session.Creator);
                $("#Resumo").val(session.Description);
                $("#Conteudo").val(session.Subject);
                $("#Pl").val(session.Keywords);

            }
        });
```

but after it does this it reloads the page how do i stop it?

One strange thing that its happened its that this only happens in google chrome

Comment: Where's the rest of your code with the page reload? Your code stops at the end of the $.ajax call but there are at least two more blocks that got cut off.

Comment: If you use an input button for your upload button you need to prevent default on submit too for the form

Comment: @Bast i dont have that

Comment: @mkaatman its just disable some divs nothing important

Comment: Put `return false;` in the behind of last line, like this `return false; });`

Comment: With this code you have here I don't see anything that restarts the page. 

It helps if you could post more snippet of your code and also this file's content http://localhost/sitePAW/exam.php .

Comment: @amulamul One strange thing that its happened its that this only happens in google chrome

Answer (score 0):

Is there any button or link being clicked?

From this code I'm guessing you have an upload form and when the value of the input changes you automatically send the information via ajax.

But if you are actually changing the input and then clicking a button (like an upload button), then this code would be called first since the input changed and then a "on click" event would go off since you clicked a button, but it is not being captured so then it just loads some hyperlink which by default if not set just reloads the page.

Commonly people set default hyperlinks to '#' so if the page reloads to something like 'locahost:8000/#' then that is probably what is happening.

Comment: that exacty it, when the input changes, i automatically send the information via ajax. One thing i notice its that its only refresh in google chrome, its very unsual

Comment: try adding this: e.stopPropagation() @props

Comment: it does not help

Comment: @mccllbear if i turn on the debbuger mode the error does not happened either